# A non-Hausdorff space with a Hausdorff subspace

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

Can anyone give an example of a non-Hausdorff space that contains a Hausdorff subspace?

Answer (score 20):

A point is Hausdorff, so any non-Hausdorff space gives examples.

Comment: Might as well take the empty subspace of any non-Hausdorff space.

Comment: Depends if you allow topological spaces to be empty. Most people do; some don't.

Comment: Wow, really? Who doesn't allow the empty space? That seems totally unnatural.

Comment: @KevinCarlson. I agree.  Every text or paper I've read allows the empty set to be a top. space . It would be awkward if it weren't. It would be like allowing $1$ to be prime: Almost every mention of primes would have to be changed to "primes greater than $1$".

Comment: @user254665 the situation is the opposite here though, allowing the empty space means that some mentions of "topological space" have to be changed to "non empty topological space", see for example the statement of Banach fixed point theorem, or the assertion "every non empty complete metric space without isolated points is uncountable" to mention the firsrt 2 that came to my mind. (That doesn't mean we shouldn't allow the empty space, just that I don't see your point)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: How about "the intersection of two subspaces is a subspace", or "every set can be given the discrete topology", or "the fiber over a point $b$ of a bundle $E \to B$" or "given a continuous map $X \to Y$, the inverse image of an open subspace is an open subspace". These basic notions all become very awkward when you exclude the empty space.

Comment: Fair enough, as I mentioned at the end of the first comment I do agree that the empty space should be a thing, I just wasn't convinced by the other user's reasons but I am a bit more now

Answer (score 19):

It is enough to consider the line with two origins, and than consider one 
of this lines as a subspace.

Comment: For those who don't recognize it from the description, add an additional point $0'$ to the real numbers and take the sets $(-\epsilon, 0)\cup\{0'\}\cup(0,\epsilon)$ to be a basis of neighborhoods of $0'$. $\Bbb R$ is a subspace, but $0$ and $0'$ are not separable.